# How to set default view in lightning experience (maybe in Summer 2016 release)

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I'm using lightning experience for all new apps.  Is it possible to set the default list view to not Recent in lightning?

This may be something that is in the Summer 2016 release which is what I'm working in for my prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible as of now. It opens 'Recently viewed' by default